# Navigating Between Screens (Won't render button)

Tags: javascript, react-native

thanks for the help firstoff. I am new to programming and am just trying to setup a way to navigate between screens. I used this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html to try and learn. Eventually, I resorted to just copy pasting the Navigator iOS into an empty javascript file to see if it would work. It will not render the button which should be the text, "Tap me to load the next scene."

This is what it should look like:

[image]

My screen looks the same, but without that text. Please help.

[This is a copy of the relevant code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuIlK.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to get your question answered, you have to ask it clearly and specifically. Please attach relevant code that you've written in order to solve your issue. Good luck!

Comment: This is not an answer, just a recommendation. Instead of IOSNavigator, try using `react-navigation` from navigation in your app. It is well documented and is the recommended one by react team. More info here : https://reactnavigation.org

Comment: Did you uploaded your code or the code that is in the guide? Please post a screenshot of what it looks like to you and your code. It could easily by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) library. And since you are looking for simple navigation, try *StackNavigator* from the provided docs, they have provided a similar helpful example for how to implement it. Goodluck!